# Error while installing Apache/2.4.37 on centos 8

Tags: apache, centos8

How do I fix this error ? Have been trying to install apache webserver on centos 8 machine. Lookign forward to your responses, thanks !!

```
 httpd.service - The Apache HTTP Server
   Loaded: loaded (/usr/lib/systemd/system/httpd.service; enabled; vendor preset: disabled)
  Drop-In: /usr/lib/systemd/system/httpd.service.d
           └─php-fpm.conf
   Active: failed (Result: exit-code) since Sat 2020-04-25 08:52:36 +0545; 10min ago
     Docs: man:httpd.service(8)
  Process: 834 ExecStart=/usr/sbin/httpd $OPTIONS -DFOREGROUND (code=exited, status=1/FAILURE)
 Main PID: 834 (code=exited, status=1/FAILURE)
   Status: "Reading configuration..."

Apr 25 08:52:28 localhost.localdomain systemd[1]: Starting The Apache HTTP Server...
Apr 25 08:52:35 localhost.localdomain httpd[834]: AH00558: httpd: Could not reliably determine the server's fully qualified domain name, using localh>
Apr 25 08:52:35 localhost.localdomain httpd[834]: (13)Permission denied: AH00072: make_sock: could not bind to address [::]:53
Apr 25 08:52:35 localhost.localdomain httpd[834]: (13)Permission denied: AH00072: make_sock: could not bind to address 0.0.0.0:53
Apr 25 08:52:35 localhost.localdomain httpd[834]: no listening sockets available, shutting down
Apr 25 08:52:35 localhost.localdomain httpd[834]: AH00015: Unable to open logs
Apr 25 08:52:36 localhost.localdomain systemd[1]: httpd.service: Main process exited, code=exited, status=1/FAILURE
Apr 25 08:52:36 localhost.localdomain systemd[1]: httpd.service: Failed with result 'exit-code'.
Apr 25 08:52:36 localhost.localdomain systemd[1]: Failed to start The Apache HTTP Server.
```

Answer (score 0):

The port 53 is the DNS port by default. So it's seems than you have bind, or something else running on your server and already using this port.

Try to change the port in your configuration or stop your bind/DNS service, but it's better to change the port in your apache configuration.

And it's seems than you have a problem with your log file too. Check your apache configuration to verify permissions and path to your log file(s).